# how to toggle between bootstrap's navbar-default and navbar-inverse with a fade using jquery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to toggle the default/inverse nav bars in bootstrap, but I can't get a fade going between them. any ideas?

```
// toggle default/inverse navbar
$('#inverse-toggle-button').click(function() {
    $('#top-navbar').toggleClass('navbar-inverse navbar-default', 1000);

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/waspinator/65WLg/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include jQuery UI to to animate the CSS change over:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/65WLg/1/)**

Comment: oh, I thought it was part of the core. any ideas why some parts fade while others jump between styles?

Comment: I'm not sure about this but it's probably because it's only animate `#top-navbar` since you toggle classes of this element, but not the button or `navbar-brand` inside it.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this

```
$('#inverse-toggle-button').click(function() {
    $('#top-navbar').toggleClass('navbar-inverse navbar-default', 1000);
    $('#top-navbar').find("div").toggleClass('navbar-inverse navbar-default', 1000);

});
```

to apply the transition to all children of `#top-navbar`